Interact with openconnect in java processbuilder
I am attempting to establish a VPN connection using a ProcessBuilder in Java. However, the process seems to block, and entering my password has no effect.
I am unable to include my username and password directly in the command line because they can change over time, and for security reasons, I am sometimes prompted for a second password.
Any help is welcome
Minimalist sample :
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

    public class VPNConnectionHandler {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[] command = {"sudo", "openconnect", "--background", "--protocol=nc", "--user=user", "serveradress"};
    
            try {
                ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
                Process process = processBuilder.start();
    
                BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
                OutputStreamWriter stdOutput = new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream());
    
                String line;
                boolean passwordPrompted = false;
    
                while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null || (line = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                        if (line.toLowerCase().contains("password:")) {
                            System.out.println("password asked");
                            if (!passwordPrompted) {
                                System.out.print("password ");
                                BufferedReader consoleReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                                String password = consoleReader.readLine();
    
                                
                                stdOutput.write(password + "\n");
                                stdOutput.flush();
                                passwordPrompted = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (line == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                int exitCode = process.waitFor();
                System.out.println("Process exited with code " + exitCode);
    
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

Using G00se idea, my concern is I don't know how to redirect the output so I can read it in Java and input via the code :
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

    public class VPNConnectionManager {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[] command = {"sudo", "openconnect", "--background", "--protocol=nc", "--user=user", "server"};
    
            try {
                ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command).inheritIO();    
                Process process = processBuilder.start();
        
                //password request
                //scanner or what ever to I can fill in the password


                int exitCode = process.waitFor();
                System.out.println("Process exited with code " + exitCode);
    
    
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

Maybe this can help me, but no idea how to make it work here :
https://github.com/agavrilov76/ExpectIt

I would immediately change this to ProcessBuilder. Strangely it's mentioned in the title but not in the code - it will give you more control. Then, as the second step, you should read stderr in a separate thread. Are you entering a password for sudo too? If so, try to get rid of that for this command in sudoers

You are right, It's been few days I am fighting this and did not put my ProcessBuilder attempt but a simple one (I will provide an edit in my code). No sudo password needed

It's certainly essential to post the real, accurate code. I'd try it myself but I have no openconnect server to log into. I take it then that openconnect asks for the password twice?

I updated my question, here you got my best attempt, using processbuilder.

OK, that's quite seriously different Why nohup and not openconnect --background?

And does it work at the terminal to echo the password into the process immediately?

From what I understood, when it is run with nohup, the process is completely detached and keeps running even If I log out. Yes the echo does the trick and works when no second password asked.

--background == Continue in background after startup See my question here. You're still not reading stderr in a separate thread. In general you've written too much code - you need to get a much smaller volume working first. OK sorry - I see you did answer. Break that command into String[] You won't need to worry about quoting then

I know that's not the best reproducible sample ahaha,  If I remove my "echo trick" I can make it simpler and get this behavior when the first password is prompted. I fail to interact with the process... I am correcty reading the log though. Do you think --background makes it easier?

Try --background in the console. Generally speaking you need to wind back to the simplest case. This is all wrong while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null || (line = errorReader.readLine() Not only are you in the same thread but you're making the reading of stderr contingent on the reading of stdout. They need to be quite independent

I provided a sample with background, It gets stucks before It even prints the System.out.println("password asked");

Process process = processBuilder.inheritIO().start(); // END of code What happens?

It works as intended in my minimalist sample O_O, I can successfully input my token and open the vpn connection. Thank you for this lead. I will try to replicate it in my full code and see how It goes when mixed with GUI. Could you provide more details on this function?

It seems like the System.out are ignored but thats not really an issue I guess

More tomorrow. Too late in UK. stdout in background

How can I interact with the process using inheritIO()?
